# What are the German equivalents of "blow away the cobwebs"?

Tags: expression

We were having a conversation in French after a concert, and I was wondering how I'd express the same idea in German. I would have said:

> Ich habe die letzten Tage damit verbracht, eingepfercht in meinem Büro über modrigen, alten Dokumenten zu brüten. Es ist wirklich eine angenehme Abwechslung, ab und zu hinauszugehen und sich zu vergnügen. Dieser schönen Musik zuzuhören  ... Ahhh, **das bringt einen wieder auf andere Gedanken**, was?

Here I was talking about how going to a concert on holiday makes for a nice diversion after spending an entire week cooped up in an office. Essentially, I wanted to express the idea of:

- *Listening to this beautiful music... Ahh, it really **blows away the cobwebs**!*

The expression "*blow away the cobwebs*" comes in handy when you want to say:

- *Doing some light exercise or going for a little walk etc helps you feel **physically** more energetic as well as **mentally** more alert.*

And this *dual* aspect -- that is, both *physically* and  *mentally* refreshed -- doesn't exactly make it easy to translate it into other languages.

I was just chatting with one of my travelling companions, a German speaker, on this matter, and we were talking about how the expression "*jdn. (wieder) auf andere Gedanken bringen*" refers mainly to a mental aspect. If so, how can I compensate for the lack of a physical connotation?

How is this idea "*blow away the cobwebs*" commonly/idiomatically expressed in German?

Comment: Your companion is right, it's only about blowing away mental fatigue.

Comment: @janka that is correct as far as the denotional semantics are concerned. You know that if you know the individual words. The usage is fitting anyhow, because *Gedanke* here may mean rather broadly *mood*. If physical fatigue subsumes mental fatigue, then mental vigour chiefly implies general vigour, alas in relative terms.

Comment: You are trying to translate from one foreign Language to another foreign language. That is very prone to go wrong. I have no doubt that the saying is used as indicated, but your interpretation seems more basic, if not fundamental than the saying.

Comment: As your conversation was in French, as you say, could you give a French example for the cobweb metaphora? It would hardly be exactly the same in French, would it?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Interestingly, a literally interpreted phrase seems to be commonly used in French, though I haven't been completely sure of it myself until today:  https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/38316/what-are-the-french-equivalents-of-blow-away-the-cobwebs

Comment: Deine Interpretation von "blowing away the cobwebs" im Zusammenhang mit leichter Gymnastik/Spaziergang basiert m.E. vollständig auf der Gymnastik/dem Spaziergang und überhaupt nicht auf der Phrase des Wegblasens von Spinnweben, der m.E. weder physisches noch mentales eigen ist.

Answer (score 2):

> Ahhh, war das belebend!
>   *(Ahhh, that was invigorating!)*

[beleben](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beleben) can be used both in a mental and a physical sense.

> Kaffee und manche Drogen haben eine belebende Wirkung – aber auch ein
>   Spaziergang oder der Stich einer Biene.
>   *(Coffee and some drugs have an invigorating effect – but also a stroll or the sting of a bee.)*
>
> Beleidigungen beleben die Kommunikation.
>   *(Insults will stimulate your communication!)*

Answer (score 1):

For your sample sentence "Listening to this beautiful music... Ahh, it really blows away the cobwebs!" and with respect to the context you provided including both mental and physical refreshment, you may say

> Diese schöne Musik zu hören... ah, das tut gut!
>
> Diese schöne Musik zu hören... ah, das bringt einen frischen Wind!
>
> Diese schöne Musik zu hören... das bringt einen auf andere Gedanken.
>
> Diese schöne Musik zu hören... da wird man doch gleich ein anderer Mensch.

These expressions are in an average register of speech, not slang or so. If you are looking for slang, perhaps this could be valid:

> Diese coole Mucke jetzt... ah, das zischt!

(Imagine the sound of opening a bottle of beer, and the mental and physical refreshment people often associate with it.)

Comment: I like much "_... da wird man doch gleich ein anderer Mensch._"

Comment: "Das bringt einen frischen Wind!" may well correspond to "second wind" in English.

Comment: ... ah, das perlt ...

Answer (score 1):

Additional to all the other good example, I want to name an old phrase:

> Das erfrischt Körper und Geist.
>
> (It refreshes body and soul.)

It suits to both areas, mentally and physically, but it sounds a little old fashioned, especially if you use it in a daily conversation with a friend.

Answer (score 0):

> Die Akkus/Batterien/Energie (wieder) aufladen *to recharge the batteries*

has the meaning and connotation that you are looking for.

For those unfamiliar with these idiom, check the following sites:

https://www.welt.de/print/die_welt/finanzen/article13503173/Was-tun-wenn-die-Batterie-leer-ist.html

https://mymonk.de/6-wirkungsvolle-wege-um-die-eigenen-batterien-aufzuladen/

https://www.plus-magazin.com/unser-leben/so-laden-akkus-auf/

https://vivilaloca.com/ausgelaugt-und-und-energielos-9-tipps-zum-batterien-aufladen/

https://bewusstgluecklich.ch/deine-batterien-aufladen-7-moeglichkeiten/

https://de.wikihow.com/Energie-wieder-aufladen

https://www.peacelife.de/ausgebrannt/

Comment: Did you make that up? It sounds as if you had made it up.

Comment: No, why would I do that? I added some examples where it's been used.

Comment: Do you have any examples of this outside of DIY life hack junk?

Comment: Despite you thinking it's "junk", does it make it any less valid? It obviously is part of the German language AND is well understandable i.e. the metaphor is quite clear.

Comment: My point is precisely that it is not part of the language proper, but marketing speach without broader use. It is also not quite transparent, as metaphors go. And it implies a sense of passivity, which is opposite to what was asked.

Comment: Den Abend auf der Couch zu liegen und nur Musik zu hören hat meine Batterien wieder aufgeladen. To me that sounds like what was asked.

Comment: @vectory   "Die Batterien wieder aufladen" is a valid, universally known and frequently used expression in German quite for what you were describing in your question. I personally do not like this metaphora, and I find it being used predominantly by people who do not think much about language. (My problem with it is that indeed it tends to present humans as robots.) But it is very common indeed.

Comment: Ich pflichte Dir bei, infinitezero, dass die Metapher weit verbreitet ist, würde aber kritisieren, dass sie die Nützlichkeit für die Arbeitswelt in den Fokus rückt, nicht so sehr die Erholung. Meine Kritik an der angeblichen Konnotation von Spinnweben wegblasen ist oben bei der Frage nachzulesen. Batterien haben m.E. nichts, was mit mentalen Zuständen korrespondiert. Physisch (Kraft, Energie) sehe ich eine parallele gegeben, aber eben zu dem, was gemeint ist, nicht zum Bild der weggeblasenen Spinnweben, die die Konnotation gar nicht haben - weder physisch, noch mental.

Comment: anyway lying on the couch surely doesn't blow way the cobwebs so what are we really talking about? I'm a little disappointed by you @ChristianGeiselmann for such overly broad statements. I'll disengage before I discharge, but not without noting that, who the hell recharges "Batterien"? Isn't that just proving a bad loan translation from a non-native speaker in the marketing department, perhaps an automated tool? It's aggrevating.

Comment: @vectory Colloquially Akku and Batterie are used interchangebly albeit technically incorrect. Could we keep this discussion on an objective level? I frankly don't care if you don't like the metaphor and are a language purist, but you must acknowledge the fact that it is a used metaphor. Language is in constant development.

Comment: @userunknown Wenn die Batterien alle sind ist das meiner Meinung nach eine ernstzunehmende Vorstufe zum Burnout. Man sollte da auf seinen Körper hören und eine Pause einlegen, ehe man sich komplett verausgabt und gar nicht mehr arbeiten kann. https://www.welt.de/print/die_welt/finanzen/article13503173/Was-tun-wenn-die-Batterie-leer-ist.html Dieser Artikel (kein Marketing "Junk") geht auf die Metapher der Lebensbatterie ein. In dem Sinne ist es eben wichtig, gerade auch für die mentale Gesundheit, den Akku frühzeitig wieder aufzuladen, ehe er komplett leer ist.

Comment: @infinitezero: Ja, und was hat das mit dem Wegblasen von Spinnweben zu tun? Nichts.

Comment: @vectory  Your remark on *Batterien* vs. *Akkus* rests upon a wrong assumption. Technically, *Batterien* are bundles of certain things, here: bundles of sources of electricity, and you can well have *eine Batterie von Akkumulatoren*. (Also an *Autobatterie* is rechargeable by definition.) - However, for the linguistic-pragmatic side of the topic this is anyway irrelevant. The expression (metaphor) in German everyday language (beginning of 21th century) is simply "Die Batterien [or Akkus] wieder aufladen", and it is not used only relating to the world of work, rather to personal well-being.

Comment: @userunknown seit wann sind denn Redewendungen immer 1:1 Übersetzungen?

Comment: @infinitezero: Redewendungen sind manchmal 1:1 übersetzbar - hier nicht und niemand hat es behauptet. Vielleicht meinst Du das sei durch meine Kritik impliziert - ist es aber nicht. Was impliziert ist, ist, dass Metaphern im Englischen wie im Deutschen gebildet werden, so dass, auch wenn der Ausdruck "die Spinnweben wegblasen2 im Dt. unüblich ist, eine wörtliche Übersetzung leicht verständlich ist. Und wenn man diese Übersetzung anstellt, stellt man leicht fest, dass die Behauptung des Fragestellers falsch ist. Er benutzt sie, um körperliche und geistige Erfrischung eines Spaziergangs zu …

Comment: … beschreiben, was ja legitim ist, und sagt dann, dass eine Übersetzung der Spinnwebmetapher schwer ist, wenn dabei der geistig und körperlich erfrischende Charakter mittransportiert werden soll, übersieht aber komplett, dass diese Bedeutung überhaupt nicht in der Spinnwebmetapher steckt, sondern nur im Kontext, in dem er sie vorgestellt hat - dem Spaziergang. Insofern erwartet er von den Übersetzungen eine Leistung, die das Original selbst nicht leistet. Wenig überraschend leistet Deine Akkumetapher dann auch nicht das verlangte. Wenn Du einen fetten Burger in einer Arbeitspause isst, …

Comment: … kannst Du sagen "Ich muss die Akkus wieder aufladen", und man wird es physisch verstehen, aber nicht geistig. Beim Spaziergang steckt es wieder im Kontext und nicht in der Metapher, dass man denkt, frische Luft und Naturbetrachtungen könnten den Geist erfrischen.

Answer (score -1):

For the physical aspect we have

> sich die Füße vertreten
>
> an die frische Luft gehen
>
> etwas frische Luft schnappen
>
> mal wieder ein bisschen Sonnenlicht tanken / abbekommen wollen.

The social aspect may be described as

> (mal wieder) unter Menschen / unter Leute gehen
>
> (mal wieder) vor die Tür gehen
>
> aus der Versenkung auftauchen
>
> wieder auf der Bildfläche erscheinen.

You have the mental aspect in

> den Kopf (wieder) frei bekommen
>
> (mal) auf andere Gedanken kommen
>
> abschalten
>
> die Arbeit vergessen / nicht mehr an die Arbeit denken müssen
>
> die Seele baumeln lassen (unfortunately rather hackneyed in the meantime)

The "cabin fever aspect" can be found in

> mir fiel die Decke auf den Kopf
>
> ich hielt das (mit dem einsamen Vor-mich-Hinarbeiten) einfach nicht mehr aus
>
> ich musste (da) einfach mal raus.

I don't know if there is an idiom that conforms exactly to your wishes. One might combine some of the sentences above or find new metaphoric expressions like:

> Ich musste mir jetzt einfach mal etwas Gutes tun, rausgehen, andere Gesichter sehen, mir den Gehirnskasten gründlich durchpusten lassen...

or

> Nach all den Tagen in "klösterlicher Abgeschiedenheit" brauchte ich dringend einen Szenenwechsel und musste an die frische Luft und unter Leute und wollte mal für ein paar Stunden auf ein anderes Programm umsteigen...

or

> Ich hatte genug einsam vor mich hingebrütet und bin losgezogen ein bisschen frische Luft und Sonne tanken... Und dann mit der wunderbaren Musik im Konzert mal richtig anders draufzukommen, das hatte mir echt gefehlt!

Comment: None of this work as a drop in replacement. What would be the resulting sentence?

Comment: @vectory: I don't know what a 'drop in replacement' is. If you want a _one English sentence - one German sentence_ solution for the OP's problem, I'm sorry to say that I don't have one. All I could do was naming German idioms or sentences that are approaching Con-gras-tue-les-chiens's idea.

Answer (score -2):

Your German friend is correct as far as the denotional semantics of *andere Gedanken* are concerned. You know that if you know the individual words. It fits anyhow. The saying is also used with sexual connotation, which surely includes physical activity. *Gedanke-n* in that sense rather means *state of mind, mood* than e.g. *opinion*.

The *cobwebs* not withstanding, the expressed sense is rather basic. Compare for example

> in Schwung bringen
>
> - *to set into motion*
> - *to repair*
>
> *Das bringt einen wieder richtig in Schwung, wa?*

cp. PIE *wenh1- "wish, desire, love", *Wunsch*, *swentos "vigour", *gesund*, En *sound*, *swen- "to sing", *Schwan*, Lat *sonus* "sound", \HweHntos "wind", Lat *ventos*, *sHwen- "sun", (viz *seHwol- with n/l alteration), *Wohl*, *sweet*, *swet*, *swell*;

Incidentally *neuen Wind* or *neuen Schwung in die Bude bringen* coexist.

Alternatively a mere *das war aufregend* does the job, unless you are asking whether your friend had a drag of a weak, too.

> aufregen, aufregend
>
> - *to excite*

By the way, I find that *cobwebs* implies idleness and lazyness, which wasn't really the case for you. Rather compare *to get the juices flowing* -- *die Säfte in Wallung bringen* does sound very archaic though.

Comment: Jemanden in Schwung bringen sounds really good, the rest is not.

Comment: @infinitezero I'm resting quite well, but collecting the comparanda was effort. What's the problem, do you know a proper etymology? Do yku not need one? Good for *you*.

Comment: I think you should clean up this answer, focus on the main points and remove the other stuff (i.e. the rest). Otherwise I feel inclided to give this a -1. Aufregend does not cover the physical aspects, so in my opinion this is in the wrong place.

Comment: "regen" literally means *to move*

Comment: Yes ... *literally*. It is only used to mean exciting though. A 90min football game can have a lot of running but still be completely boring. You would never say it was *aufregend*.

Comment: that's not a working example unless *I* was the player, in which case, indeed, I would find it boring and consequently play less vigorously. But take a good internet fight for example, sometimes I have to get up and walk it off.